# Add value to the first empty column of DataFrame for specified index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of variables. For each variable, I add the variable to DataFrame `results` on a new row, and then run function `order_analysis`:

```
for i in var_list:
    order_number = i
    row = (results.last_valid_index())
    new_row = row + 1
    results.loc[new_row, 'Order'] = order_number
    order_analysis()
```

DataFrame `results` after adding new row and before `order_analysis`:

```
   Order  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  Column8
0  123    NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

As mentioned, for each variable (i)  `order_analysis` is run. The function results in at least a `Number_Result` and `Date_Result`. If the `Project_Result` is only spaces, it runs `order_analysis` again. Based on my data, after max 4 runs, there is a `Project_Result` (hence 8 columns). Then it returns to the `var_list` loop.

```
def order_analysis():

    # (Majority of the function)

    # Results of the analysis:
    Number_Result = df1['Number'].loc[df1.index[indexbelow0]]
    Date_Result = df1['Date'].loc[df1.index[indexbelow0]]
    Project_Result = df1['Proj.'].loc[df1.index[indexbelow0]]

    if str.isspace(Project_Result):
        print('Number:', Number_Result)
        print('Date:', Date_Result)
        order_analysis()
   else:
       return
```

Currently, I print the `Number_Result` and `Date_Result`. Instead, I want to add these results to the first empty column in the DataFrame on the row which was added based on the variable (i). So for example, for variable (123) `order_analysis` runs 2 times, for variable (456) `order_analysis` runs 4 times and for variable (789)`order_analysis` runs only 1 time. DataFrame `results` should then look like this:

```
   Order  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  Column8
0  123    Result   Result   Result   Result   NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
0  456    Result   Result   Result   Result   Result   Result   Result   Result
0  789    Result   Result   NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

However, unlike using `last_valid_index()` to find the first empty row, I have no knowledge on how to find the first empty column on a specific row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [`last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html) is also a Series method. So if you slice a row, this will give you a column index.

That said, you can also slice the NA column indices and use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to find the first one (if any, else `None`):

```
col = next(iter(df.columns[df.iloc[0].isna()]), None)
```

Or, if you're sure there is a match:

```
col = df.columns[df.iloc[0].isna()][0]

# or
col = df.iloc[0].isna().idxmax()
```

Output: `'Column5'`